# Remove Spinner on Inline Keyboard

Tags: py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

How can I get rid of the spinner in Telegram bot inline button?  I'm using the pyTelegramBotApi (Telebot) library.

Remove spinner **:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id)
```

Use this.

Answer (score 0):

It will stop when you answer the callback query.

See [CallbackQuery](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery) in Telegram Api Docs.

> NOTE: After the user presses a callback button, Telegram clients will
> display a progress bar until you call answerCallbackQuery. It is,
> therefore, necessary to react by calling answerCallbackQuery even if
> no notification to the user is needed (e.g., without specifying any of
> the optional parameters).

Also Python Telegram Bot documentation:

https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.callbackquery.html